# Can I upgrade to SRAM GX Eagle from Shimano Acera 9 Speed?

Tags: gears, upgrades, groupsets

Thinking about upgrading my gear set to SRAM GX Eagle 12-Speed Groupset 175mm from a Shimano Acera 9 Speed 40/30/22 MTB chainset

Would this be compatible?

Comment: Chances are the rest of the bike isn’t worth the expensive upgrade

Answer (score 2):

To clarify things, with a SRAM GX Eagle groupset that consits of a crankset, GXP bottom bracket, chain, gear shifter, cassette and rear derailleur the only part that might cause incompatibility issues is the cassette because the [XG-1275 11-50 cassette](https://www.sram.com/sram/mountain/products/xg-1275-eagle-cassette) requires an [XD freehub driver body](https://www.sram.com/sram/mountain/products/sram-xd-driver-body) (XD body has extra space for 10 and 9 cogs, while Shimano-style body does not).

Still, you've got several options to choose from:

1. Get a more expensive XG-1295 or XG-1299 11-50 cassette (Shimano freehub body compatible).
2. Get a cheaper [Sunrace CSMZ90 11-50 casstte](http://www.sunrace.com/en/products/detail/csmz90)  (Shimano freehub body compatible).
3. If your rear hub has compatible XD freehub body for sale, get it and a regular XG-1275 10-50 cassette.
4. If there's no XD freehub body available for your rear hub, you can buy an XD rear hub and relace the rear wheel. Or buy a complete, compatible wheel.

Comment: So to clarify i could use the SRAM GX Eagle groupset if i also purchased a SRAM XD™ Driver Body? and this would be able to be fitted to my bike?

Comment: It's hard to tell if you can purchase XD body at all because you did not tell the model of your rear hub. It might be that there's no XD for the hub at all, given then lower budget nature of current crankset.

Comment: The hubs are Shimano HB-TX505 ive done a bit more reading and i think i definetly need new hubs and or wheels but this Is now what im unsure about. The rims are CUBE ZX20 29ers , could you maybe reccomend a decent wheel or just hub if thats all i would need to replace! thanks a lot by the way

Comment: Sorry Josh, but we don't do product recommendations here. I'd factor in the sum you are willing to spend and local availability. Maybe you'd be able to find a decent second-hand hub at local classifieds or something at you local bike shop. Rims/hubs might get very expensive depending on your preferences.

Comment: Once you get to thinking about new wheels to upgrade the drivetrain you are contemplating replacing (at least) half of the entire bike - better at this point to start thinking about a whole new bike with components all at the same level.